# Specify redirect URL after signing in console

Tags: docusignapi

We are creating envelopes via the SOAP interface utilizing a template; our business owner has asked that after signing confirmation is complete rather than redirect to our internet homepage (as is the default for envelopes sent under our account) users be sent to specific "thank you" pages based on role.

Is there any way to specify such a URL in the SOAP envelopeinfo/recipient construction?

Answer (score 0):

If recipients are accessing the DocuSign envelope by clicking the link in the Email that DocuSign sends to them when it's their turn in the routing order (i.e., they are "remote" recipients), then there is no way to implement customized landing pages on a per-envelope or per-recipient basis.

However, if recipients are accessing the DocuSign envelope via your application (i.e., they are "embedded"/"captive" recipients), then it is possible to implement customized landing pages on a per-envelope or per-recipient basis.  When using the **RequestRecipientToken** operation to request the URL that will launch a recipient's DocuSign envelope, you can dynamically construct the URL(s) such that they contain any number of additional querystring parameters/values that you specify.  For example, consider this (C#) code sample taken from pages 101-102 of the DocuSign SOAP API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf):

```
// Construct the URLs based on username 
DocuSignWeb.Recipient recipient = envelope.Recipients[0]; 
DocuSignWeb.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs urls = new 
DocuSignWeb.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs(); 
String urlBase = baseURL; 
urls.OnSigningComplete = urlBase + "?event=SignComplete&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnViewingComplete = urlBase + "?event=ViewComplete&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnCancel = urlBase + "?event=Cancel&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnDecline = urlBase + "?event=Decline&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnSessionTimeout = urlBase + "?event=Timeout&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnTTLExpired = urlBase + "?event=TTLExpired&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnIdCheckFailed = urlBase + "?event=IDCheck&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnAccessCodeFailed = urlBase + "?event=AccessCode&uname=" + recipient.UserName; 
urls.OnException = urlBase + "?event=Exception&uname=" + recipient.UserName;
```

In this example, the **uname** querystring parameter in each URL is being dynamically populated with the recipient's name.  The receiving page, then, will be able to use the value of this querystring parameter to display customized messaging for each recipient. (This example uses the parameter name **uname** and populates it with the user's name -- but you can add whatever querystring parameters you need to provide info the receiving page can use to render customized messaging.)